# Using a loop to extract data to excel

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

first timer here and I'm new to Excel 2013 so if I screw up somewhere let me know!

I am trying to gather stats from the Detroit Red Wings from 1932-2014
I recently learned that I can pull data from a website via Data->Get External Data->From Web

So far I have been opening a new sheet, pulling the data into Excel, and renaming the sheet to match the year

Below is my attempt at a loop but it isn't working

What ideally would happen is
I run a macro and it creates a new sheet and then fills in the data for that sheet, for every year from the 1932-33 season through the 2013-2014 season and renames the sheets to match the years.

(EX: I run the macro and it creates a sheet titled "1932-33" pulls the data from the website and puts it into the sheet. Then it creates a sheet titled "1933-34" pulls the data from the website and puts it into the sheet)

**Important Notes**
here is the web address of the site with 1932-33 season

http://www.whatifsports.com/nhl-l/profile_team.asp?hfid=11&season=1932-33

I found that to change the year you just adjust the "1932-33" at the end of the URL to whatever year you want.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub firstLoopAttempt()
'
' firstLoopAttempt Macro
'

'
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1942 To 2014

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.whatifsports.com/nhl-l/profile_team.asp?hfid=11&season=1942-43" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "profile_team.asp?hfid=11&season=1942-43"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Next i
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A29").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A30").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A31").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A32").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A33").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A34").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Cells.Replace What:="View Player Profile on Hockey-Reference.com", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A4").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 21.91
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Range("B4").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 4.09
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Range("C4").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 3.09
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a for loop around it, but never use "i" for anything. That's probably why it's not working. ;)

Try something like this (warning this is untested, and has no conversion error checking implemented):

```
Dim startYear As Integer
Dim endYear As Integer
Dim strStartYear as String

For startYear = 1942 To 2014

    ' Convert the current start year number to a string, then take the last two characters and assign to strStartYear
    ' So 1942 becomes "42".
    strStartYear = Right(CStr(startYear),2)
    ' Convert the string back into an (integer) number, and add 1 to create the End year.
    endYear = CInt(strStartYear)+1

    ' Use these variables in your other commands to specify the start/end year
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.whatifsports.com/nhl-l/profile_team.asp?hfid=11&season=" & startYear & "-" & endYear _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "profile_team.asp?hfid=11&season=" & startYear & "-" & endYear
        'other stuff omitted  for brevity
    End With
Next startYear
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm trying to run the macro but I'm getting _Run Time Error '5' Invalid procedure or argument_ I looked at that line 5 of the code and it is the '.CommandType=0' line

Comment: That's a different question. :) Start a new question and post the code you've tried (this time), and also post the exact error code you're getting.

Comment: That error message isn't saying it is on line five.  It is saying that some piece of code has a run-time error which is error #5.  Where does the code highlight when the error message appears?